# how to write logfiles to kafka using logstash?

Tags: logstash-configuration, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send my log files to kafka topic using logstash. Not sure what configuration is required in logstash configuration file to send output to kafka. If anyone has done anything similar ,kindly share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logstash output block for Kafka would look like:

```
 output {
    kafka {
        topic_id => "your_topic_id"
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html) is documentation.